# Call Class Method after StartActivity

Tags: android, class, instance-variables

I've got two classes. Class1 and Class2 - Both extend Activity.

Class1 Launches on the program launch and when you click a button it's meant to slide to Class2 - this works fine.

However Class2 has a TextView which I want to change the text of depending on which button is clicked - but I can't for the life of me work out how to do it

I'm using startActivity(Class1.this,Class2.class); to slide across which obviously creates a new instances of Class2

I've also tried creating an instance of Class2 and then calling startActivity(Class1.this,myVar.getClass());

but the result is the same, any ideas how I call Class2.someMethod(); so that it effects the newly displayed Class2 instance? or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm using startActivity(Class1.this,Class2.class); to slide across which obviously creates a new instances of Class2

No, you are not, as that will not compile. You are probably using:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Class1.this,Class2.class));
```

> I've also tried creating an instance of Class2 and then calling startActivity(Class1.this,myVar.getClass());

That won't compile either. Here is the documentation for [`startActivity()`](http://goo.gl/Wp60).

> any ideas how I call Class2.someMethod(); so that it effects the newly displayed Class2 instance?

You don't.

> or am I going about this the wrong way?

If you want to pass data to the new `Activity` -- and the data is simple, like you might put in parameters of a URL in a Web app -- then package it as an `Intent` extra:

```
Intent i=new Intent(Class1.this,Class2.class));
i.putExtra("some key", "some value"); // there are many different types of data you can package
startActivity(i);
```

Then, in `Class2`, in `onCreate()`, you can call `getIntent().getStringExtra("some key")` to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thank you, I did some research and found Extras were the only real way to do this

Just to note:

     I've also tried creating an instance of Class2 and then calling                     startActivity(Class1.this,myVar.getClass());

     That won't compile either.

This does compile..... The problem was never getting it working it was just passing data to it.